# Wordpress how can I know if the pagination is active?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Has Wordpress a function or something like that?I need a way to check if there are any page links(Older Entries | Newer Entries)to be displayed or not.

Best Regards,

Comment: Maybe you should ask this at superuser.com

Comment: Well it's about wordpress pluginizing. Seems fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Already asked on Superuser - http://superuser.com/questions/57266/wordpress-how-can-i-know-if-the-pagination-is-active

Comment: what do yo mean with 'any page links(Older Entries | Newer Entries)' .... is it about a post or a page (page has child page and it can be show in pagination form) ? or just general pagination ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the [new_posts_link](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc#dqvo9yHru0E/wordpress-1.5.2/wp-includes/template-functions-links.php&q=next_posts_link%20package:wordpress&l=427) function, you'll see a $max_page and $paged vars.

If the $pages is higher to 1, there is a previous page link.
It it's smaller to $max_page, there is a next page link.

So you can do the following functions :

```
# Will return true if there is a next page
function has_next_page() {
    global $paged, $max_page;
    return $paged < $max_page;
}

# Will return true if there is a previous page
function has_previous_page() {
    global $paged;
    return $paged > 1;
}

# Will return true if there is more than one page (either before or after).
function has_pagination() {
    return has_next_page() or has_previous_page();
}
```

Comment: And if it's none of them?I need somthing like this: if($verfication !== false){ //show pagination div....

Comment: Well if it's none of them, you're on the first page and there isn't any pagination to display. If you want a function that'll give you true or false, you can code it with those two vars.

Comment: The function has_next_page() doesn't seem to work on WP3.03, as $max_page doesn't seem to have any value. The has_previous_page() works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As Marcus said, the function `has_next_page()` doesn't work for newer wp versions, so you can simply use `get_previous_posts_link()` and `get_next_posts_link()` inside an if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Although like many i use the pagenavi plugin by Lester Chan.right http://lesterchan.net/wordpress/readme/wp-pagenavi.html